# Integrate $f(x) = g(x)\cdot{}h(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions

I need to find the anti-derivative of $f(x)=g(x)\cdot{}h(x)$. How do I do that?

Comment: [WolframAlpha wasn't very helpful.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+f%28x%29*g%28x%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generally easy way. For example, we know the antiderivative of both $\sin x$ and $\frac{1}{x}$, but there is no elementary antiderivative of their product $\frac{\sin x }{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

For the product of some functions, you can use [integration by parts](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx). The link should help give you some insights as to when that's appropriate.

In your case, there's no way of knowing the relation between arbitrary functions, but there often is a relation between the product of two functions, as you'll see, when integration by parts is the tool of choice!

Comment: Wowwww. A nice Avatar Amy.

Comment: I need a help, can you tell me how to put the link in the answer so that it appears as you did here with " integration by parts" and not as an URL?

Comment: Hi, @Thus: you can manually put name you want to give in brackets, then immediately follow with the URL in parentheses `[integration by parts](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegrationByParts.aspx)` as in the case above, or simply click on the image icon in at the top left of your answer, which will prompt you to enter a URL, and then highlights the area (bracketed) to enter the link's reference.

Comment: Than you! Thank you very much! :-D

Comment: You're welcome, @Thus !

Answer (score 1):

There is no general formula for the anti-derivative of *arbitrary* functions. If you have specific functions in mind, try integration by parts.